# Cross-Domain Tracking Works With Sessions but Not Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

## **Cross-domain tracking works normally with a user's session - but not with events.**

For example Googling the site, landing on the homepage, and then proceeding to the cross-domain site **properly records "Organic" as the medium.** (That has been validated by using Realtime data in GA)

However, Googling the site, landing on the homepage, and then proceeding to the cross-domain site and completing an event **incorrectly records "Direct" as the medium** for that event.

#### Is there a reason cross-domain tracking is working for sessions - but not working for events/goals?

GTM Setup has been configured with:
- 5 domains pushing to a 'Rollup' GA account
- autoLinker = true
- Cookie Domain = auto
- Auto Link Domains = site1.com,site2.com,site3.com,site4.com,site5.com

GA Setup for the 'Rollup' account has been configured with:
- Referral Exclusion List = site1.com,site2.com,site3.com,site4.com,site5.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the all GTM tags for the events are using the same GA settings as well.

Comment: Ok got it: With every event though it is using the proper UA-XXXXX Analytics Setting

Within that UA-XXXX variable it is also configured to have: allowLinker = true, Cookie Domain = auto, Cross Domain Tracking = site1.com, site2.com, etc.

Comment: So the normal pageview analytics is using the UA-XXXX variable (where within that variable it is configured for cross-domain tracking) ------ and every event is also using that same UA-XXXX variable

Comment: If you can tell me what the site is, I would be able to tell you where it is wrong.

Comment: I wish I could, but it is a sensitive client with locked-down data. I will send you a link to preview some screenshots I took of the issue if that helps.

Comment: No problem, if you can post screenshots or a report using "Google Tag Assistant" chrome plugin, it will help.

Comment: Awesome thank you thank you so much in advance. working on it right now

Comment: ok @XTOTHEL https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iImdDrp0U3PegvZ3aNfsOm-MaOtN4ZAhp7QCQ-FrVLU/edit?usp=sharing